# Unity Setactive function does not work in pointer events

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to `SetActive(true)` a pause menue after clicking on a pause button in Unity. My `PauseGame()` function works completly fine but when I call it in an `OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)` event (because I want my Button function to evoke after the first click not when the mouse is up) the game pauses but the pause menue does not activate.

```
public void PauseGame()
    {
        if (player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().contactOnGround == true) 
        {
            pauseMenue.SetActive(true);
            gamePaused = true;
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            pauseMenueClosed = false;
        }
    }
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if(eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.name == "PauseButton")
        {
            PauseGame();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you get the reference to `pauseMenue`? Is it a public member that you drag into the inspector or are you using `GameObject.Find`?

Comment: I drag it into the inspector. Not sure but when I try it with Find it does not work at all because its not active so it cant find it I assume?

Comment: It works completly fine when I use the Onclick button event but I dont want it to be evoked after the MouseUp. When i try with the OnPointerDown it does not activate even though it activates on OnClick for instance. I tested it with Debug.Log(pauseMenue.active); and when I call SetActive(true) on pauseMenue it shows true but it is not active in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked when I call `pauseMenue.SetActive(false)` and comment it out and then it worked. I use OnPointerDown and GetMouseButtonDown simultaneously thats why SetActive(false) and SetActive(true) were called on one click. This was not the case with OnClick thats why I was confused.